# How to use python cgi?

Tags: python, html, web, cgi, web-development-server

I really need some help in python cgi programming, I try to use a python script to write on excel file from a form in html.

This is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi,cgitb
cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir="/cgi-bin")

#import libraries for write on excel file
import xlrd
import xlwings

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

# Get data from fields
mail = form.getvalue('email')
psw  = form.getvalue('password')

print ("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print ("<html>")
print ("<head>")
print ("<title>CGI Program - Get value from html form</title>")
print ("</head>")
print ("<body>")
print ("<h2>Email : %s <br>Password : %s</h2>" % (mail, psw))
print ("</body>")
print ("</html>")

wb = xlwings.Book('data.xlsx')  
Sheet1 = wb.sheets[0]

Sheet1.range(1, 1).value = mail
Sheet1.range(1, 2).value = psw

wb.save()
wb.close()
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky11b.jpg)

I can get the data from the form and print it in a new html page but I can't write it on excel.

If you have a complet documentation about python cgi programming, how to use functions... I'll be grateful.

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please edit this post to include the text of the script in the question.

Comment: The cgi module is documented in the standard library documentation at https://docs.python.org. But unless you are obliged to use cgi, I'd use a framework like flask or bottle.  It's _much_ easier to develop against a modern web framework than cgi.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you for your interaction. I'm not a web developer, I just have a program in python that I must integrate into an application. I found that python cgi can make this but how I didn't really find the answer. I don't have to use necessary python cgi, if you have an other solution let me know please.

Comment: Is `data.xlsx` in the same directory as your Python cgi script?

Comment: @Booboo yes in the same folder, the script works well if I execute the python file directely.

Comment: The only think I can think of is that when the script is running the current directory is *not* the directory in which the script resides. Try fully qualifying `'data.xlsx'` with the full path to this file.